# Unknown strategy "local", nodejs and passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I checked for answers to this common isue but it seems its pretty a case-by-case, and I cant figure out wth is wrong with my code. Here I set up first my local sign up and then the log in, when I try to login, regardless of the input, I get the "Unknown strategy 'local'" error.

```
var express    = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var mysql = require("mysql");
    var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
    var session = require('express-session');
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

    // expose this function to our app using module.exports
    module.exports = function(passport) {
        passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
        });

        // used to deserialize the user
        passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        connection.query("select * from users where id = "+id,function(err,rows){ 
          done(err, rows[0]);
        });
        });

        passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {

            connection.query("select * from users where email = '"+email+"'",function(err,rows){
          console.log(rows);
          console.log("above row object");
          if (err)
                    return done(err);
           if (rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
                } else {

            // if there is no user with that email
                    // create the user
                    var newUserMysql = new Object();

            newUserMysql.email    = email;
                    newUserMysql.password = password; // use the generateHash function in our user model

            var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users ( email, password ) values ('" + email +"','"+ password +"')";
              console.log(insertQuery);
            connection.query(insertQuery,function(err,rows){
            newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

            return done(null, newUserMysql);
            }); 
                } 
        });
        }));

        passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

             connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '" + email + "'",function(err,rows){
           if (err)
                    return done(err);
           if (!rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
                } 

          // if the user is found but the password is wrong
                if (!( rows[0].password == password))
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

                // all is well, return successful user
                return done(null, rows[0]);     

        });



        }));

    }


    app.use(passport.initialize());


    ...
```

EDIT: Forgot to write this part. Im calling it with:

```
   app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login',
                                   failureFlash: true })
);
```

Comment: Did you configure your strategy with the passport?

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined the strategy as `passport.use('local-login', ...)`, I guess you should use `passport.authenticate('local-login')` in your endpoint definition(which is not shown).

Comment: I forgot to write it down here, but yep, im using passport.authenticate.

Comment: Then, will it work if you change `passport.authenticate('local', ...)` to `passport.authenticate('local-login', ...)` ?